# Linq to SQL object child properties in GridView

Tags: .net, sql, linq, wcf, linq-to-sql

For example, in my WCF, if I have a Customer table and an Order table that have an association to each other on Customer ID.

I want to get the Count of the number of Orders for each Customer.

In regular VB code I can just do this:

```
Dim CustID As Integer = 1234
Dim cust As New MyService.Customer()
cust = cust.GetCustomer(CustID)
Response.Write(cust.Orders.Count)
```

The above code works fine but if I want to access the same from within a GridView, it doesn't seem to react the same way (albiet, from a different method but I'm applying the same pricipals to each method though)

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsCustomers" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetCustomers" TypeName="MyService.Customer" />

<asp:GridView ...>
...
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Orders.Count" HeaderText="Order Count" />
</Columns>
...
</asp:GridView>
```

So how could I do something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try adding a partial method to the Customer class called OrderCount and reference that in your BoundField.  Right click you dbml file and go to View Code then add.

VB

```
Partial Public Class Customer

    Public ReadOnly Property OrderCount As Integer
        Get
            Return Me.Orders.Count
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

C#

```
public partial class Customer
{
    
    public int OrderCount {
        get { return this.Orders.Count; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any other solutions?
I mean, is there any other way to set the value itself like in a repeater by server tags Text="<%# Eval( "Orders").Count %>"

Comment: Yeah

<asp:templatefield HeaderText="Order Count">
<itemtemplate>
<asp:Label ID="OrdersCountLabel" runat="server"
Text='<%# Eval("Orders.Count") %>' />
</itemtemplate>
</asp:templatefield>

Should work.